# Hide TopTabNavigator inside StackNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I am using `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` from `react-navigation` and each Tab has StackNavigator. How can I hide Top tabs after opening Stack screen? Currently using Expo managed with Redux.
Here's the code:

```
const favStack = createStackNavigator();
const loserStack = createStackNavigator();
const gainerStack = createStackNavigator();
const activeStack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const MarketsTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

export default class App extends Component {
  state = { loading: true };

  favStackScreen = () => (
    <favStack.Navigator>
      <favStack.Screen name="Favorites" component={Favorites} />
      <favStack.Screen name="Stock" component={Stock} />
    </favStack.Navigator>
  );
  loserStackScreen = () => (
    <loserStack.Navigator tabBarVisible="false">
      <loserStack.Screen name="Losers" component={Losers} />
      <loserStack.Screen name="Stock" component={Stock} />
    </loserStack.Navigator>
  );
  gainerStackcreen = () => (
    <gainerStack.Navigator headerMode="float">
      <gainerStack.Screen name="Gainers" component={Gainers} />
      <gainerStack.Screen name="Stock" component={Stock} />
    </gainerStack.Navigator>
  );
  activeStackScreen = () => (
    <activeStack.Navigator>
      <activeStack.Screen name="MostActive" component={MostActive} />
      <activeStack.Screen name="Stock" component={Stock} />
    </activeStack.Navigator>
  );

  MarketsTabScreen = () => (
    <MarketsTab.Navigator
      style={{
        paddingTop:
          Platform.OS === "ios"
            ? Constants.statusBarHeight
            : StatusBar.currentHeight,
      }}
    >
      <MarketsTab.Screen
        name="Losers"
        component={this.loserStackScreen}
      ></MarketsTab.Screen>
      <MarketsTab.Screen
        name="Gainers"
        component={this.gainerStackcreen}
      ></MarketsTab.Screen>
      <MarketsTab.Screen
        name="MostActive"
        component={this.activeStackScreen}
      ></MarketsTab.Screen>
    </MarketsTab.Navigator>
  );

  async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      Roboto: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf"),
      Roboto_medium: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf"),
      ...Ionicons.font,
    });
    this.setState({ loading: false });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <AppLoading style={styles.container} />;
    }

    return (
      <Provider store={store.store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={store.persistor}>
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Tab.Navigator>
              <Tab.Screen name="Favorites" component={this.favStackScreen} />
              <Tab.Screen name="Markets" component={this.MarketsTabScreen} />
            </Tab.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

For managing state I am using Redux and all my components are class(so can not use Hooks).
Components being used: (Gainers, Losers, MostActive as Top Tabs) and Favorites as Bottom Tabs. All of them should have access to Stock component.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can set the `tabBar` prop of your `MarketsTab` navigator to a function that returns `null` like this:

```
MarketsTabScreen = () => (
  <MarketsTab.Navigator
    tabBar={() => null}
    style={{
      paddingTop:
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? Constants.statusBarHeight
          : StatusBar.currentHeight,
    }}>
    <MarketsTab.Screen name="Losers" component={this.loserStackScreen} />
    <MarketsTab.Screen name="Gainers" component={this.gainerStackcreen} />
    <MarketsTab.Screen name="MostActive" component={this.activeStackScreen} />
  </MarketsTab.Navigator>
);
```

You can still swipe to the screens in the tab navigator, but the top tab bar won't be shown.